# Difference between 'npm add' and 'npm install --save'?

Tags: javascript, npm, npm-install

I've searched through the web and still can't get if there is any difference between `npm add <package>` and `npm install --save <package>`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

npm `install` and `add` are aliases. **The `--save` option is deprecated.**

Since NPM 5, packages are saved automatically; [there is no `--save` option](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install).

Answer (score 11):

`add` is just an alias for `install`.

So the only difference is `--save`, which modifies `package.json` with the dependancy.

> ```
> $  npm add --help
>
> npm install (with no args, in package dir)
> npm install [<@scope>/]<pkg>
> npm install [<@scope>/]<pkg>@<tag>
> npm install [<@scope>/]<pkg>@<version>
> npm install [<@scope>/]<pkg>@<version range>
> npm install <folder>
> npm install <tarball file>
> npm install <tarball url>
> npm install <git:// url>
> npm install <github username>/<github project>
>
> aliases: i, isntall, add
> common options: [--save-prod|--save-dev|--save-optional] [--save-exact] [--no-save]
> ```

Comment: I used to think the same way. But as I see the dependencies (package.json) are being updated as you run `npm add ...`.